# Java - Taking a 2-D array and returning the sum of the rows of that array using a 1-D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that takes a two-dimensional array of integers (`t`) and returns a one-dimensional array (`sums`) that holds the sum of all the elements for a particular row WITHOUT using arithmetic operators and using a for-each loop.

```
public static int sumArr(int[] m) { // Returns the sum of a row of a 1-D arr
        int sum = 0;
        for (int number : m) {
            sum = sum + number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

This is a separate method that returns the sum of a row within a 1-D array. As you can see, I use a for-each, however; I need to implicate this method in order to do the above task.

Comment: `the sum of all the elements for a particular row WITHOUT using arithmetic operators` - how would you calculate the sum without addition operator?

Comment: Use an explicit Iterator if you should not use a for-each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
int[][] t = ...
int[] sums = new int[t.length];
int i = 0;
for (int[] row : t) {
   sums[i++] = sumArray(row);
}
```